# Is there a drill holster that is not attached to a belt?

Tags: drill

I am in the process of building a second floor to our container home which includes the mindless task of screwing thousands of screws into sheets of OSB.

So far I have only used drill holsters or pouches that attach to your belt or the ones that come with a belt like contraption.
[image: Drill Holster]

I find them both very inconvenient in terms of carrying and picking up the screwdriver quickly and they keep pulling on my pants.

I would love to have something similar to a camera strap like these ones:
[image: Professional Quick Action Camera Shoulder Strap with Quick Release Clip]​​

That allow me to:

- quickly switch between adjusting the OSB board and screwing in the screws
- lift the screwdriver above my head without it being constrained by the contraption
- doesn’t restrain my movement too much and doesn’t dangle around uncontrollably
- cherry on top if it has something to attach one or more bags for the screws

Does anyone know if such a thing exists and what it's called?

Comment: Interesting idea... I suspect you'll have to home-brew it, though. A couple of alternatives: a lightweight impact driver with a belt clip can hook onto your trousers (pocket or waistband) without dragging them down too badly. Or, go to a full workbelt with suspenders and put something like the linked holster on that belt. It'll also have plenty of room in the pouches for screws.

Comment: Hi Stefanie, welcome to Woodworking! First off be aware that direct shopping queries are off-topic for this SE so technically we can't Answer this, but we always try to help. I think your included photo pretty much gives you the solution that could work, and well enough that you don't need to overthink it and try to come up with a better solution given your limited actual need (see next comment): a standard camera strap, one karabiner + a couple of cable ties to give you something to clip to and there you go.

Comment: Now I don't want this to come across as dismissive which is why I put this second, my first thought was how about the tried-and-trusted technique of putting the driver down on a nearby surface and picking it up when you need it? Like so many things in construction and woodworking *the* way to get through it may be to make a mental adjustment; just put your head down and get to it. Might help to remember that it wasn't too long ago that every one of those — not thousands ;-) — of screws would have been driven in manually, and if they needed to pre-drill holes they were done by hand too!

Comment: Once I answered this one it occurs to me this might be a better fit for DIY SE. Maybe move this there? Or the OP can search there first anyway.

Comment: I'd think that a DIY solution of attaching the pouch in the first pic to the strap in the 2nd pic is most likely your way of achieving what you're after. TBH, though, after having assembled a deck a couple of years ago and a shed last summer, the only time I put the driver down was to go get more screws to refill my tool-belt pouch or another board for decking. Putting the driver in the pouch between each screw is a definite no-go unless you're not working quickly or don't have the grip strength/duration to hold it for more than a couple at a time.

Comment: I edited my post and removed the question regarding a DIY alternative and the question regarding where to buy it. After the edit, does this meet topic guidelines and can be reopened?

Comment: I voted to reopen. If a strap/hanger thingie remains a high priority for you I still think a DIY solution as I outlined above is your best bet; you'd be ready to go today if you already have a camera strap.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's still a high priority for me. I think my use case - someone working by themselves with not much upper body strength - might not be the usual one, but still relevant to some when installing ceilings and walls. I already have some equipment to diy a solution and I am happy to share that as an additional Q+A on the DIY site. I think the post might be interesting to others with my use case, even if such a thing does not exist yet.

Answer (score 4):

Makita drills (and I'm sure others do as well) come with an optional hanger so you can safely hang it upside-down when you are up on a ladder. It is intended to slip into a belt (not the fancy holster you show) but it'll go anywhere that hook can conveniently fit.

When I was in the trades those up on the ladders would rig up a receiver for that hook on the ladder itself. If you can find a way to hang such an awkward mass safely using a home-brew harness you can try that. I've never seen any after-market harness -- we'd just wear a minimal pouch-and-belt and hook the drill into that or hang it from the ladder. Some guys even had a lanyard attached to it so they didn't drop their precious tool (or brain their less-precious co-workers).

Comment: Yup, some of my DeWalt cordless tools come with belt clips. I find it so useful, I bought a package and applied them to about every other tool that would take one. (The circular saw? Not so much...)